# Multiple use of Vaadin LitTemplate

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-flow

```
@JsModule("./views/parents-editor-view.ts")
@Tag("parents-form-cloner-view")
public class DesignParentsCloner extends LitTemplate {
    @Id("fondsTemplate")
    private VerticalLayout fondsTemplate;
...
}
Other class:
DesignParentsCloner cloner = new DesignParentsCloner();
VerticalLayout templateLayout = cloner.getFondsTemplate();
addComponent(templateLayout); -> throws Trying to detach an element from parent that does not have it.
```

[Limitation of LitTemplate](https://vaadin.com/docs/latest/create-ui/templates/limitations) lists:
You can add components and elements to a template structure, but you can’t remove anything present in the original template. However, overriding component properties is possible.

Is there any way to detach the VerticalLayout and add it somewhere else?

Edit: Why do I need this? One example: In the template I define a component which allow to enter an address (name, street, zip code, country, region, ...). Elsewhere in the form I allow to create an unlimited number of addresses per user (like Amazon).

Comment: In case, this is an X-Y-problem: could you please elaborate, what you
plan to use this for?  You want to build up something on the client, and
then steal it from there on the server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple answer:
addComponent(templateLayout) was incorrect
add(cloner) did the trick

Answer (score 2):

> Is there any way to detach the VerticalLayout and add it somewhere else?

If you need to add/remove that layout in the component from Java, you should not add it in the template at all. Instead you should add there a slot, which looks roughly like this in your template.

```
<div>
  <slot name="name"></slot>
</div>
```

If you need more than one slot, use named slots. Then add the component to the slot like this in Java code.

```
component.getElement().setAttribute("slot", "name");
this.getElement().appendChild(component.getElement);
```